# Which are the differences between vue-cli and vue-cli-service?

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I've used Vue for some time now, but I'm just getting started with the CLI and I got a bit confused.

I installed [`@vue/cli`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue/cli) and if I type `vue` in the command line, I get:

```
Usage: vue <command> [options]

Options:
  -V, --version                              output the version number
  -h, --help                                 output usage information

Commands:
  create [options] <app-name>                create a new project powered by vue-cli-service
  add [options] <plugin> [pluginOptions]     install a plugin and invoke its generator in an already created project
  invoke [options] <plugin> [pluginOptions]  invoke the generator of a plugin in an already created project
  inspect [options] [paths...]               inspect the webpack config in a project with vue-cli-service
  serve [options] [entry]                    serve a .js or .vue file in development mode with zero config
  build [options] [entry]                    build a .js or .vue file in production mode with zero config
  ui [options]                               start and open the vue-cli ui
  init [options] <template> <app-name>       generate a project from a remote template (legacy API, requires @vue/cli-init)
  config [options] [value]                   inspect and modify the config
  upgrade [semverLevel]                      upgrade vue cli service / plugins (default semverLevel: minor)
  info                                       print debugging information about your environment

  Run vue <command> --help for detailed usage of given command.
```

I created a project with `vue` and I needed to install [`@vue/cli-service-global`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue/cli-service-global) for some reason that I can't remember.

After that, however, I noticed:

```
'vue-cli-service' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

And that's because I had to install [`@vue/cli-service`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue/cli-service). Now, when I type `vue-cli-service` in the command line, I get:

```
  Usage: vue-cli-service <command> [options]

  Commands:

    serve     start development server
    build     build for production
    inspect   inspect internal webpack config

  run vue-cli-service help [command] for usage of a specific command.
```

---

Apparently, I can build, serve, and inspect with both CLI tools. My question is - what's the difference between them? Both the readme of `@vue/cli` and `@vue/cli-service` have nothing but a link to [this page](https://cli.vuejs.org/) where no answer is given to that question.

What can I do with one that I can't do with the other? Do I need both?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`@vue/cli-service-global` is a package that allows you to run `vue serve` and `vue build` *without any local dependencies*.

`@vue/cli-service` is a package that actually doing those `vue serve` and `vue build`, both `@vue/cli-service-global` and `@vue/cli` depend on it.

If you're using `@vue/cli` then you don't need to install another two independently, since it already has `@vue/cli-service` in its dependencies.

---

**Added:** Just to be sure, I'll explain it more:

**`@vue/cli`**:

1. `add`, `create`, `config`, `ui` and other commands
2. `build` and `serve` commands through `@vue/cli-service-global` package
3. `inspect` command through `@vue/cli-service` package (local dependency)

**`@vue/cli-service-global`**:

1. `build`, `inspect` and `serve` commands through `@vue/cli-service` package

**`@vue/cli-service`**:

1. `build`, `inspect` and `serve` commands

So, you need to install `@vue/cli` only and remove other two.

---

**Added:** Clarification about using `vue-cli-service`:
When you create a project using `vue create` command, `@vue/cli` makes a link to `vue-cli-service` binary inside `./node_modules/.bin` of created project.

Then you can use it like this:

1. Access it directly as `vue-cli-service` inside `npm` scripts (`package.json`):

   ```
   "scripts": {
     "watch": "vue-cli-service build --watch"
   }
   ```
2. Access it from the shell: `./node_modules/.bin/vue-cli-service build --watch`.
   You can even add `./node_modules/.bin` to you shell `PATH` and access it from the shell directly as `vue-cli-service`.

Comment: Not quite. When I installed `cli`, I was unable to use `vue-cli-service`. I needed to install `cli-service` globally too so I can use `vue-cli-service build --watch` since `vue build --watch` tells me `watch` is an unknown option. I don't think that `cli` simply uses the commands of `cli-service`. Doesn't appear that way. Even if they are dependencies of each other - why am I able to use them independently? Shouldn't there be just `cli` which is used with `vue`? Could you expand on that?

Comment: @HristiyanDodov Ah, I see. I've updated my answer with additional information.

Comment: @HristiyanDodov There was a mistake in my answer. `@vue/cli` uses `build/serve` through `@vue/cli-service-global`, which uses them through `@vue/cli-service`.

Comment: So basically, `cli-service` has the core building functionality, `cli-service-global` allows you to run the commands without local dependencies, and `cli` is a wrapper around `cli-service` with added functionality for creating projects and configuring stuff?